# C# Covariance generic parameter assignment/casting (implicit conversion)

Tags: c#, generics

I've a interface:

```
interface IInterface<T1, out T2> {};
```

and an abstract class implements `IInterface<>`

```
abstract class AbsClass<T2> : IInterface<String, T2> {};
```

and other abstract classes inherits from `AbsClass<>`:

```
abstract class AbsAbsClassString : AbsClass<String, String> {};
abstract class AbsAbsClassTimeSpan : AbsClass<String, TimeSpan> {};
```

and finally,

```
class CClassString1 : AbsAbsClassString {};
class CClassString2 : AbsAbsClassString {};
class CClassTimeSpan1 : AbsAbsClassTimeSpan {};
class CClassTimeSpan2 : AbsAbsClassTimeSpan {};
// and so on...
```

In my C3 code, I've declared a `List<IInterface<String, Object>>`

```
IList<IInterface<String, Object>> list = new List<IInterface<String, Object>>();
list.Add(new CClassString1());
list.Add(new CClassString2());
list.Add(new CClassTimeSpan1());
list.Add(new CClassTimeSpan2());
```

On each `list.Add(*)` sentence, compiler tells me:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection(IInterface(String,object)).Add(IInterface(String,object))' has some invalid arguments
>
> Argument 1: Cannot implicitly convert type CClassString1 to  IInterface(String,object). An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

If I test with:

```
IInterface<String, Object> i;
CClassString1 cs1 = new CClassString1();

i = (Interface<String,Object>)cs1;
```

The last sentence throw an exception telling it's impossible to do the cast.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Your current code does not compile. You define `AbsClass` with one type parameter, but use it with two. Maybe it is just completely different class?

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't compile due to the problem exposed and answered by @Jakub.

Comment: You claim that all four `list.Add(*)` lines give you compile error. Jakub's answer only explain last two. You also claim that this `(Interface<String,Object>)cs1` — compiles and throw exception in runtime. But, as [you can see yourself](https://ideone.com/JAwwr9), after fixing some issues in your code it compiles and run without exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic interface convariance and contravariance only works with reference types. `TimeSpan` is a value type, so `IInterface<string, TimeSpan>` cannot be cast to `IInterface<string, object>`.

That's because variant casts are reference conversions - they do not change the representation of the object, they only change the compile-time type of the reference.

Comment: I've tested creating a `ReferenceValue<T>` with `IInterface<String, ReferenceValue<TOut>`. It seems to be working...